# SVN pre-commit script change from perl to shell

Tags: svn

In my SVN repository pre-commit file written using perl. Could you please help me, how can I change the perl script to shell?

I have tried to make copy of the pre-commit file to "pre-commit_original" and I have written below code in"pre-commit" file:

```
[hooks]$ cat pre-commit
#!/usr/bin/sh

REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"

/usr/bin/perl pre-commit_original "$REPOS" "$TXN"
```

after that I tried to commit a change it's throws error as "`Can't open perl script "pre-commit_original": No such file or directory`"

Could you please help me on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `/usr/bin/perl FULL/PATH/TO/pre-commit_original "$REPOS" "$TXN"`

Comment: @Lazy Badger: Hi, Thanks for the response. I have tried to given like "/usr/bin/perl $repo_path/hooks/user/pre-commit.pl "$REPOS" "$TXN"". but it throws the same error. Could you please suggest me any alternative option?

Comment: Check permissions and ownership (`ls -la PATH/TO/REPO/HOOKS`)

Comment: @Lazy Badger: Hi, I got the code...! Actually "pre-commit_original" file is in "hooks" folder only. while call we should give command as "/usr/bin/perl $REPOS/hooks/user/pre-commit_original "$REPOS" "$TXN"" then it will work. there is no "user" folder in "hooks" folder even though we need to give the path like "$REPOS/hooks/user".  Any way thatnks for the support. I don't know how can I vote for your comments